# Difference between getActivity() and view in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

What is the difference between

```
getActivity().findViewById(...)
```

and

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_v, null);
view.findViewById(...)
```

in Fragment (when converting Activity to Fragment)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is that with `getActivty.findViewById(...)` you are finding views in the scope of activity (activity's layout). With `iflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_v, null); view.findViewById(...)` you are inflating the layout of your fragment and then finding view's in that layout.

But since your fragment is attached to the activity, you will find the view bothways, but I suggest you are finding view's for your fragment in your fragment's scope since there may be several fragments that have common layouts meaning there may be several view's associated with the same ID and that makes the `getActivity().findBiewById(...)` method unreliable

Answer (score 0):

When you call `findViewById` with `getActivity()` you are telling Android to find the `View` within the `Activity`'s layout, since `Fragments` are hosted inside `Activities` it will return you the correct `View` if its in the hierarchy.

By calling findViewById with the inflated `View` or in fact the `getView()` method provided by the framework you are essentially telling Android to find that `View` within the `Fragment's` view hierarchy, this should be your preferred approach as the `findViewById` algorithm will have to look for your View from a lesser set of View's and hence the search will be faster.

I'll leave you with this explanation about getView() from the developer docs.

```
getView()
Get the root view for the fragment's layout (the one returned by onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)), if provided.
```