# Create a GridView of images inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview

I am trying to create a Grid View inside a Fragment. I have implemented the adaptor class and the respective overriden methods. But while running it throws an exception in the line :

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener (this);
```

stating that the gridView object is a NULL pointer.

Here is my code (very similar to [Google Sample](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)) :

```
public static class OcrOverrideFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    // The Adaptor Class for the grid view
    public class ImageAdaptor extends BaseAdapter{

        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdaptor (Context c)
        {
            mContext = c;

        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return (long) position;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public int getCount (){

            try
            {
                String[] f = mContext.getAssets().list("OcrSampleImages");
                return f.length;
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                LogUtil.d (TAG,"OCR_OVERRIDE gave " + e);
            }
            return 0;
        }

        // For each of the items in the grid, this method will be called
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ImageView imageView = null;

            try
            {
                String[] f = mContext.getAssets().list("OcrSampleImages");

                if (convertView == null) {
                    imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
                }
                else {
                    imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
                }

                // Setting the appropriate image for each gird item
                imageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromAsset("OcrSampleImages"+System.getProperty("file.separator")+f[position]));

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                LogUtil.d (TAG,"OCR_OVERRIDE gave " + e);
            }

            return imageView;
        }
    } // End Of ImageAdaptor Class

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ocr_override, container, false);

            GridView gridView = (GridView) (getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ocrgridview));
            gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdaptor(v.getContext()));
            gridView.setOnItemClickListener (this);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> adaptorView,View v,int i,long l)
    {
        // Implementation details unncessary

    }
```

Comment: Show where its throwing null pointer exception?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid I have already indicated the line where I am getting the error...The exact error line is mentioned in the comment

Comment: Change it to `GridView gridView = (GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.ocrgridview);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) (getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ocrgridview));
```

To

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.ocrgridview); //Note "v" not activity
```

Comment: I will try this ASAP and get back...Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

> getActivity ()

**Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.**

*But*

> View v

**Getting a reference to the** `v` **in layout file**.

That's why we call second approach instead of first .
You can visit below for better answer

**[Difference between getActivity() and view in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779933/difference-between-getactivity-and-view-in-fragment)**