# Do I need to create another activity inside fragment in order to display images while clicking on item of navigation bar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, android-fragmentactivity, android-navigation-bar

I have 5 items on navigation bar with fragment of each item. What I want is, I want my images to display in every click to the item of navigation bar which I have stored on drawable folder. I am able to display the text but whenever I try to display images with gridview unfortunatley the apps gets error. Can anyone help me please. I tried to put gridview in acitvity_main.xml and the following code in MainAcitvity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}
```

My images will display in main page which I want to display after clicking on item of navigation bar. Note: All the 5 items in navigation bar are for to display images of different category. In short, I have 10 images each for 5 items in navigation bar i.e 50 images in drawable folder. while clicking the first item I want 10 images to be appear and same as 10 images while clicking second item on naviagtion bar and so on.

Comment: add your more code and the error log

Comment: You can simply change the image data in activity on the click event of navigation menu item

Comment: I'm sorry but your problem is not clear to me.

Comment: You can use, recycler view in every fragment and apply gridlayout manager to that recyclerview. and in recyclerview's adater you can dynamically load required images

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit what I want is. I have 5 navigation item with 5 fragment each and I want those 5 fragment to be filled with images.

Comment: @VivekSolanki what about java code? where should i write? in mainactivity.java or in each fragment?

Comment: guyz, my question is similar to this guy [google] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656555/create-a-gridview-of-images-inside-a-fragment?rq=1) the difference is I have 5 fragments and all the 5 fragments are for images of different category.

Comment: Plus I am confused where should I write gridview. Should i write in activity_main.xml or in each xml file of fragment :( How do i contact with each fragment with their xml file respectively for the gridview

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NavigationDrawer then it is better to go with writing recyclerview for every fragment.

So, in each fragment you can add code something like below :
[Please consider that everything is defined and initialized, and yes i am using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for loading images

```
// Create global configuration and initialize ImageLoader with this config
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new 
    ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

    rv_photo_grid = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_photo_grid);
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager;
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
    rv_photo_grid.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    photoUrls.add("image1");
    photoUrls.add("image2");
    photoUrls.add("image3");
    photoUrls.add("image4");
    photoUrls.add("image5");

    photoGridAdapter = new PhotoGridAdapter(this, photoUrls);

    rv_photo_grid.setAdapter(photoGridAdapter);
```

Your adapter can be like this :

```
public class PhotoGridAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotoGridAdapter.ItemHolder>  {
private List<String> arraylist;
private Activity mContext;
private boolean isGrid;
ImageLoader imageLoader;

public PhotoGridAdapter(Activity context, List<String> arraylist) {
    this.arraylist = arraylist;
    this.mContext = context;
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
}

@Override
public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)              
View v =    LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                          .inflate(R.layout.item_photo_grid, null);
ItemHolder ml = new ItemHolder(v);
return ml;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemHolder itemHolder, int i) {
    imageLoader.displayImage(arraylist.get(i),itemHolder.iv_photo);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (5);
}

public void updateDataSet(List<String> arraylist) {
    this.arraylist = arraylist;
}

public class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
View.OnClickListener {
    protected TextView tv_more_images_count, artist;
    protected ImageView iv_photo;
    protected View footer;

    public ItemHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.iv_photo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);
        tv_more_images_count = (TextView) 
             view.findViewById(R.id.tv_more_images_count);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
 }
```

}

Recyclerview in each fragment can go like this :

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_photo_grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

And item_photo_grid.xml be like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="2dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/default_placeholder" />
```

Hope this help!

Happy Coding ^_^