# getActivity().findViewById(int id) returns null even after fragment has completed building

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm following the android training in [android's website](http://developer.android.com). I am stuck at some point in fragments. The problem is that I can't get the reference to my textview in a fragment.

```
TextView view = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article_s);
```

I have two fragments in one activity. One is a plain simple `ListFragment` and the other is a plain simple `TextView`. Here is fragments and activity layout xml files.

ArticleFragment:

```
<!-- This is fragment_article.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Some Text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:id="@+id/article_s"/>
```

MainActivity (My container to all fragments)

```
<!-- This is activity_main.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.example.bora.fragmentsmyway.HeadlinesFragment"
    android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp" />

<fragment
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.example.bora.fragmentsmyway.ArticleFragment"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

There is a public method in my `ArticleFragment` which takes a string to update the content of the textview of itself:

```
public void updateView(String article) {
        TextView view = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article_s);
        try{
            view.setText(article);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

After all the views are created, I call the `updateView` method from my MainActivity. But I get a `NullPointerException` when I try to find the article TextView. I have tried cleaning, changing the TextView's resource id.

However I have found a solution for this problem. I don't know why but it seems to work when I wrap `TextView` with a `LinearLayout` in the `fragment_article.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="..."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some Text"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:id="@+id/article_s" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But I am wondering this: How can, in the tutorial samples, above code work and can't work when I wrote? I checked every code letter by letter but there is no difference between mine ant theirs. Is it because of the versions?

I'm working with the API 23 which is marshmallow.

Comment: change only to R.id.article to R.id.article_s

Comment: **I don't know why but it seems to work when I wrap TextView with a LinearLayout in the fragment_article.xml**. Can you shows us the code??

Comment: @Raghunandan I have added.

Comment: Made an edit to the answer. check if ithelsp

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you fragment is attached to the activity before calling `updateView`

this

```
 TextView view = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article_s);
```

will give you NPE cause it does not belong to the activity

The views belong to the Fragments in which case you do

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
 TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article_s);
```

Specifically, the fragment can access the Activity instance with getActivity() and easily perform tasks such as find a view in the activity layout:

Read Communicating with activity @ https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

So you use `getActivity` to find views that belong to activity which is not the case in your code.

Edit -

Wrapping it with a `LinearLayout` should not make any difference as it is just a viewgroup. If you just need a single `textview` no need for `LinearLayout`.

Read the accepted answer at : [Difference between getActivity() and view in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779933/difference-between-getactivity-and-view-in-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

This is return NPE because your try to find the wrong id.
There are two different way you can resolve issue.

> 1) First one

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Some Text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:id="@+id/article"/> 

TextView view = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article);
```

Another way keep your XML as it is & try to do below change in java code.

> 2) Second One

```
<TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some Text"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:id="@+id/article_s"/> 

TextView view = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article_s);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like this inside a fragment class by the way you should upload your main activity codes or your fragment class if you are using it inside the main activity, you don't need to use `getActivity()`

if it is inside a fragment class you need to apply it like this:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout_xml, container, false);
        TextView AboutUs = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.id_of_textview);
```